# robot command not found if installing robotframework with pip --user

Tags: robotframework

I am getting an error when execute robot scripts through CMD (windows)

> 'robot' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file"

My team installed Python in C:\Python27 folder and I installed ROBOT framework and all required libraries with the following command

```
"python -m pip install -U setuptools --user, python -m pip install -U robotframework --user"
```

We are not authorized to install anything in C drive and all libraries were installed successfully. But when I try to execute the scripts through CMD  then getting error.

Note:

1. All Robot Libaries are installed in "C:\Users\bab\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages"
2. I did set up the Env variables with above path
3. Scripts are working through ECLIPSE and using the command below

Command

```
C:\Python27\python.exe -m robot.run --listener C:\Users\bab\AppData    \Local\Temp\RobotTempDir2497069958731862237\TestRunnerAgent.py:61106 --argumentfile C:\Users\bab\AppData\Local\Temp\RobotTempDir2497069958731862237\args_c4fe2372.arg C:\Users\bab\Robot_Sframe\E2Automation
```

Please help me, as this step is very key to integrate my scripts with Jenkins

Comment: It would help if you tried to apply some formatting to your question. Right now you have code, text, and lists all combined into one big hard to read paragraph.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks a lot, it works for me. Just write the following in the terminal:

```sh
python -m robot "your file name"
```

In this case the file name is `TC1.robot`, so the command would be:

```sh
python -m robot TC1.robot
```

Answer (score 3):

I was getting an error when executing robot scripts through linux command of

```
sudo pip install robotframework
```

and the below command worked for me:

```
sudo pip3 install robotframework
```

Answer (score 1):

I've  installed robotframework using this command "sudo pip3 install robotframework" in jenkins server. and now my jenkins pipeline script can now run my robot scripts

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very comfort with Windows environment, so let me give my two cents:

1) Try to set the PATH or PYTHONPATH to the location where your robot file is

2) Try to run robot from python script. I saw that you tried it above, but take a look at the RF User Guide and see if you are doing something wrong:

https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-robot-and-rebot-scripts

maybe just

```
python -m robot ....
```

is fine

Comment: Thanks, It worked , first I cd to the Site packeges where Robot is installed and ran with Python -m command  cd Users\babo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\robot>C:\Python27\python.exe -m robot.run -d Results C:\Users\bab\Robot_Sframe\E2EAutomation\Test_Suite\Enrollment_834.robo

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, It worked , first I cd to the Site packeges where Robot is installed and ran with Python -m command  cd Users\babo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\robot>C:\Python27\python.exe -m robot.run -d Results C:\Users\bab\Robot_Sframe\E2EAutomation\Test_Suite\Enrollment_834.robo
We can close this